# Show that $\ln (x^2+a) +\frac{b}{x^2+a}$ attains a global minimum at $\pm \sqrt{b-a}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, optimization

Let $0<a<b$ and let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the function defined by

$$f(x)= \ln (x^2+a) +\frac{b}{x^2+a}$$

Consider the problem of minimizing $f$. Since $f$ is continuously differentiable a necessary condition for a local minimum is

$$f'(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2+a}-\frac{2bx}{(x^2+a)^2}=0$$

One can check that the only three possible candidates are $x=0$ and $x=\pm \sqrt{b-a}$ with values $f(0)=\ln(a)+b/a$ and $f(\pm \sqrt{b-a})=\ln(b)+1$. Using the inequality $\ln(1+x)<x$ for $x>0$ one can show that $f(0)>f(\pm \sqrt{b-a})$, so the only candidates are in fact $\pm \sqrt{b-a}$.

How to show that $f$ attains a global minimum at $x=\pm \sqrt{b-a}$? I would like to show it without computing $f''(x)$.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid taking a second derivative if you check how the sign changes of the first derivative.  If the sign is negative on the left side of a critical point and positive on the right side, you have a minimum.  If it is positive on the left side and negative on the right side, you have a maximum.

$f'(x) = \frac {2x(x^2+a - b)}{(x^2+a)^2} = 0$

If $0<a<b$

when $0<x<\sqrt {b-a}, f'(x) < 0$ and when $x>\sqrt {b-a}, f'(x) > 0$

showing that this is a minimum.  A similar analysis works around $-\sqrt {b-a}$  and around $x=0$ shows that it is a local maximum.

If $b<a$ then is is not possible for $x^2 = b-a$ and no minimum.

And, if $a<0$ you have asymptotes at $\pm \sqrt a$ and not defined in between.

Finally, if $0<a=b$ there is only one critical point.  But the same analysis will show that this too is a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you are avoiding computing $f''(x)$ but I do have an idea about bypassing directly using the second derivative. Here "directly" menas that my method is still about second derivative in essence, but we don't need to compute it completely.

As you have shown,
$$
f′(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2+a}−\frac{2bx}{(x^2+a)^2}\\
=2x(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{b}{t^2})\\
=2x\cdot\frac{1}{t}(1-\frac{b}{t})
$$
where $t=x^2+a$.

We know that $\frac{1}{t}(1-\frac{b}{t})$ is actually a quadratic function about $\frac{1}{t}$ so the sign changes at the point $\frac{b}{t} = 1$.

Furthermore, we know that at $\pm\sqrt{b-a}$ the equation $\frac{b}{t}=1$ holds and for $x<-\sqrt{b-a}$, $\frac{b}{t} <1$; for $-\sqrt{b-a}<x<0$, $\frac{b}{t}>1$. And at the point $x=+\sqrt{b-a}$, it's similar.

This tells us that the first derivative changes its sign at $\pm\sqrt{b-a}$, which is sufficient to show these two points are local min.

Answer (score 0):

Set $t = \frac {b}{x^2+a}$, then $f(x) = lnb - lnt + t = g(t)$, $g'(t) = -\frac1t + 1$, $g''(t) = \frac1{t^2}\gt 0$.
So $f(x) = min\{f(x)\}$, iif $g(t) = min\{g(t)\}$, iff $t = 1$, iff $x = ±\sqrt{b−a}$.